# how to get html string from source code and send in MailMessage as Html Body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-2, html

i have a huge page with lot of divs..

VIEW:

```
<div id="contractOverview">
        <div id="econtract">
             <p>a lot of content here</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to get just one id which is "econtract" from the whole view, after that call a method in the controller, which sends an e-mail by smtp; this is not the problem.
The problem is to get the html string from "econtract".

CONTROLLER ActionResult:

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
m.From = new MailAddress("ir@w3mentor.com", "Raja Item");
m.To.Add(new MailAddress("su@w3mentor.com", "Sekaran Uma"));
m.Subject = "html email coming!";

//Specify an HTML message body
m.Body = "<div id="econtract">a lot of content here</div>"
m.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Please help, sitting many hours already..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('econtract').innerHTML
```

You can then post this back to the server using AJAX or a form to the server.

Comment: how can i do it without ajax? just with asp.net mvc 2

Comment: You need to assign the value to a form field, then submit the form to the server.